# Tensorflow import error: Naive Pip Windows 10

Tags: tensorflow

having problems while

screenshot given below. I want the solution badly.

> import tensorflow as tf

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgghK.png

Answer (score 0):

You're using tensorflow-gpu but do not have CUDA / cuDNN installed on your computer.

Shor answer: run `pip unintall tensorflow-gpu` and `pip install tensorflow`.

Long answer: Install [CUDA / cuDNN](https://medium.com/@acrosson/installing-nvidia-cuda-cudnn-tensorflow-and-keras-69bbf33dce8a)